# local module not found in azure function

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, python-import

I try to reproduce [this setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Cazurecli-linux%2Capplication-level#folder-structure) to import local modules into my code.

Here is my folders structure, similar to previous link:

[image: folders structure]

and my code :

**hey/**init**.py**

```py
import logging

from shared.helloworld import sayhello # the way I would like to do it -> doesn't work

# from shared import helloworld # as per documentation, but doesn't work
# import shared.helloworld # as per documentation, still doesn't work


import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info(sayhello("from log"))
    return func.HttpResponse(
             sayhello("from http response"),
             status_code=200
        )
```

**shared/helloworld.py**

```py
def sayhello(name : str) -> str:
    return "hello world " + name
```

I have kept `shared/__init__.py` empty as I have read this is an ok practice and that file was only present to mark this folder as importable.

No matter what syntax I use for importing my module, I always hit the same error :

> Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> 'shared'. Troubleshooting Guide:
> https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound Stack: File
> "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py",
> line 315, in _handle__function_load_request func =
> loader.load_function( File
> "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py",
> line 42, in call raise extend_exception_message(e, message) File
> "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py",
> line 40, in call return func(*args, **kwargs) File
> "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py",
> line 85, in load_function mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in
> import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package,
> level) File "/home/site/wwwroot/hey/__init__.py", line 3, in 
> from shared.helloworld import sayhello

The documentation linked in error message does not concern local import and I'm out of idea here.
Anyone having a clue why my import doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was provisionning my az func with terraform, my issue was I didn't provide this block :

```hcl
resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "auth_func" {
    ...
    application_stack {
      python_version = "3.9"
    }
```

In case someone else is facing this issue, here a few path to investigate :

- make sure you `python runtime` is set in the azure function
- `__init__.py` from imported package is empty or is designed to work in azure function (no local references)
- `requirements.txt` contains all external modules you're using in code

Answer (score -2):

The documentation explains it better . Refer here[Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Cazurecli-linux%2Capplication-level#import-behavior)